# Неправильный вывод элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы

Ввожу элементы массива , одновременно переводя их из char в цифры , а потом в интовый массив , потом в обратном порядке записываю цифры в массив, и в первом цикле все в порядке , но вот во втором после ввода второго числа цифры записываются в массив некорректно.Например,ввожу 536~ (тильда нужна как знак окончания ввода) и он записывается в массив в обратном порядке , потом проделываю тоже со вторым , ввожу 111~ и тут уже ошибка , получатеся следующее

```
                    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 3 5
```

Но со вторым уже хуже:

```
                    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 -38
```

как исправить подобное ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
const int N = 10;
void main(void)
{
int  K[N] = { 0 }, I[N] = { 0 }, V[N];
int p = 0,r=0, i = 0, j = 0,f=0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    K[i] = 0;
    I[i] = 0;
    V[i] = 0;
}

i = 0;

do {
    p = getchar() - '0';

    if (p != 78) {
        K[N - 1 - i] = p;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else break;
} while (true);

for (r = 0; r<N; r++)
    printf("%4d", K[r]);

printf("\n");
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdin);

do {
    f = getchar() - '0';

    if (f != 78) {
        I[N - 1 - j] = f;
        j = j + 1;
    }
    else break;
} while (true);

for (r = 0; r<N; r++)
    printf("%4d", I[r]);
printf("\n");


_getch();
}
```

Небольшой апдейт, стал писать с другой переменной , но эти -38 все еще остались

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в `getchar` попадает `\n` - ASCII код `10`. Отнять код нуля (`48`) - получится `-38`.

```
do {
    f = getchar() - '0';

    if (f > 0 && f < 9) {
      I[N - 1 - j] = f;
      j = j + 1;
    }

    if(f == 78)
      break;
} while (true);
```

Comment: лучше сказать что `c-'0'` имеет смысл только для `'0' <= c && c <= '9'` остальное зависит от реализации или вообще к неопределённому поведению ведёт.

Comment: @jfs пытался объяснить откуда берется число -38

Comment: проверять что символ цифра следует до вычитания, а не после.